# Who is the author of Gott Fun Avrohom?

Tags: authorship, yiddish, motzei-shabbos

Gott Fun Avrohom (Yiddish: גאט פון אברהם) is a prayer written primarily in Yiddish and in some Ashkenazi communities it is recited by women before Havdalah. (Sometimes it is also recited by men as well.)

The Complete ArtScroll Siddur and Siddur Kol Yaakov HaChadash both attribute the prayer to Rabbi Levi Yitzchak of Berditchev.

> Today, many women maintain the custom of reciting Gott fun Avrohom before Havdalah. Rabbi Levi Yitzchak of Berditchev, traditionally recognized as the author of this prayer, however, wrote that it should be recited three times by men, women, and children, and that this recitation would help assure success in the ensuing week. - Siddur Eitz Chaim, The Complete ArtScroll Siddur, Nusach Sefard, First Edition page 653.
>
> נמצא בכתבי קודש של הרב הקדוש רבי לוי יצחק מברדיטשוב זצ''ל, בעל המחבד ספר קדושת לוי - סידור קול יעקב החדש, הוצאת הספר אדיר, עמוד 350

Despite all this, I read somewhere online that it was not authored by Rabbi Levi, because Gott fun Avrohom appears in siddurim from before his time! So who is the real author, and who should I believe?

http://judaicaused.blogspot.com/2014/11/the-origin-of-mis-attribution-of-got.html

Comment: ["The Yiddish prayer 'God of Abraham' which many Jewish women recite at the close of the Sabbath is erroneously attributed to him."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi_Yitzchok_of_Berditchev)

Comment: I heard from aYeke that this minhag was in his family without any link with RLY from Berditshov

Comment: The Siddurim from before his time have a different version which is shorter. The version that is printed in the Artscroll and attributed to him is a version that was written by him.

Comment: The weekly [Olim Letrufoh 5768](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50332&pgnum=36)  has an article on גאט פון אברהם . 
The author, נתן נטע מאשקאוויטש, points out that although the prayer is ascribed to Rabbi Levi Yitzchak of Berditchev, it predates him. Rav Levi Yitzchak "תיקנה במעט והעתיקה בכתבי קודש שלו " edited it slightly and included it in his holy writings. Apparently there are many (50?) different versions and  Rav Levi Yitzchak fixed the version to be said. See [here](http://forum.otzar.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=10494#p98341) .

Comment: @kouty, see my answer

Comment: @Noach MiFrankfurt very good. Now I understand why some yeke families I know say it every motsash

Comment: @kouty, we certainly wouldn't say it if   A were authored by RL"Y

Comment: @Noach MiFrankFurt ?????????????

Comment: @kouty, mein Großvater ist in Frankfurt geboren. Ich bin in Boston geboren.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt - Ja wirklich? Das wusste Ich nicht.

Comment: Warum (15.....)

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt - Weil dein Benutzername ist "MiFrankfurt" und du bist sehr gut informiert auf Jeckishe minhagim. Oh, und RL''Y war ein guter Mann.

Comment: Wo habt du Deutsch gelernen? Deutschsprechen ist nicht so "common„ in frommer Judenthum, ebenfalls in der Jekkischwelt!

Comment: Ich habe Deutsch gelernt weil Ich bin von Deutscher Abstammung, obwohl Ich bin nicht a Jecke. Nach Ich Jiddisch gelernt, lernen Deutsch war leicht. Kennst du ein Deutsches Siddur?

Comment: R' Rallis Wiesenthal habt sein “Tefiloh Sefas Yisroel„ nach Minhog Frankfurt a/M. Ebenfalls, die Rödelheimer Siddurim und Machsaurim sind von Goldschmidt Verlag hier (http://www.victorgoldschmidt.ch/gebetbuecher-1/index.php) verkauft.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt - Danke schön! Ist die Koren Siddur nach Minhag Frankfurt?

Comment: Nein, Der Korensiddur ist ein siddur nach Minhog Paulin mit Kabbalistische Gebeten nach der Ar"I und der Gr"O. Koren habt welche Girsoauß von Minhog Aschkenaz licht ולעולם לא נבוש in die wochentaglich Ngamidoh. Mein Orenensiddur ist ein altes Koren mit meine girsoische Anmerkünge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While Isaac lays out the common claim of Levi Yitzchok Berditschever (as well as the fallacy thereof) he doesn't go farther back. Per the author of the [Treasures of Ashkenaz](http://TreasuresofAshkenaz.wordpress.com) blog, the authorship question for *Gott von Avrohom* goes [further back](https://treasuresofashkenaz.wordpress.com/2015/09/18/from-medieval-ashkenaz-techinah-supplication-to-iconic-segulah-the-chasidic-transformation-of-g-d-of-abraham-%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%99-%D7%94%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%A9/) than the birth of Chassidus, being rishonic in nature. While the individual who first composed a vernacular techinah in this form will likely never be identified, we can safely dismiss R' Levi Yitzchok as a contender – since [print versions](http://judaicaused.blogspot.com/2014/11/the-origin-of-mis-attribution-of-got.html) appear prior to his lifetime (c. [1740-1809](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi_Yitzchok_of_Berditchev))

Answer (score 3):

[*Levi Yitzhak of Berditchev; portrait of a Hasidic master*](http://www.worldcat.org/title/levi-yitzhak-of-berditchev-portrait-of-a-hasidic-master/oclc/799940?referer=di&ht=edition), by [R' Samuel H. Dresner](http://articles.chicagotribune.com/2000-05-03/news/0005030314_1_hasidic-jewish-life-jewish-theological-seminary) says (p. 108) "both words and tune are ascribed to [Levi Yitzhak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi_Yitzchok_of_Berditchev)," but in an endnote (on p. 215), he cites [Samuel Horodetzky](http://yleksikon.blogspot.com/2016/02/shmuel-aba-horodetski-samuel-horodetzky.html) in *ha-Hasidut v'ha-Hasidim* (p.82, n. 16) questioning the authorship, and claiming that "a similar version of the song was already in use in Germany and Alsace, from where it may have found its way to the Ukraine [where R' Levi Yitzhak lived - IM]."